# Is it ok to query several times for a single post?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using postgresql to build a web service.
One post on my website consists of multiple items(dynamic number) and each item can have multiple images(will be saved on AWS S3 and db will have its url).

To normalize my DB, I made a separate tables for many-to-many relation connected by a junction table.

My question is, to fully load one page, i need to first query items that belong to the post. then query all images that belong to each item meaning that I need several nested(not sure what to call it) queries.

Using Join will reduce the length of the SQL but DB will be doing the same amount of work which I think is a lot for a single post.

Is there any efficient way to handle this?

Comment: Typically running a single query that processes a lot of rows is faster than running multiple statements that process a few rows each

Comment: And if the query runs into a timeout, you are probably fetching too many data and should paginate.

Answer (score 0):

This is the job for the SQL to do all that joins. A single query is the right way to do that. Unless you are dealing with a huge amount of data. In that case, you can get a performance gain by sending parallel subqueries to multiple read-only database replicas.